# Split an array of nested JSON objects using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to split an array of nested json objects using **jq**. Could someone please help to resolve this issue and provide a better solution?

Sample input is:

```
{
  "storeId": "1412",
  "templateCheck": [
    {
      "rom": 37,
      "updateDate": "2021-05-09 07:53:17",
      "lhb": "2021-05-09 06:32:41",
      "templateCode": "REGULAR",
      "lId": "50-19-78-5C",
      "sk": "830066",
      "skUpdateDate": "2020-07-21 05:37:07",
      "battery": 30,
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "rom": 37,
      "updateDate": "2021-05-09 07:54:02",
      "lhb": "2021-05-09 06:32:41",
      "templateCode": "REGULAR",
      "lId": "50-1B-FE-6E",
      "sk": "740541",
      "skUpdateDate": "2021-03-22 05:59:00",
      "battery": 30,
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "rom": 37,
      "updateDate": "2021-05-09 07:52:05",
      "lhb": "2021-05-09 06:32:41",
      "templateCode": "REGULAR",
      "lId": "50-1C-22-6E",
      "sk": "846760",
      "skUpdateDate": "2021-05-08 03:34:22",
      "battery": 29,
      "status": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Expecting output as:

```
{
    "storeId": "1412",
    "templateCheck": [
      "rom": 37,
      "updateDate": "2021-05-09 07:53:17",
      "lhb": "2021-05-09 06:32:41",
      "templateCode": "REGULAR",
      "lId": "50-19-78-5C",
      "sk": "830066",
      "skUpdateDate": "2020-07-21 05:37:07",
      "battery": 30,
      "status": 1
    ]
}
{
    "storeId": "1412",
    "templateCheck": [
      "rom": 37,
      "updateDate": "2021-05-09 07:54:02",
      "lhb": "2021-05-09 06:32:41",
      "templateCode": "REGULAR",
      "lId": "50-1B-FE-6E",
      "sku": "740541",
      "skUpdateDate": "2021-03-22 05:59:00",
      "battery": 30,
      "status": 1
    ]
}
{
    "storeId": "1412",
    "templateCheck": [
      "rom": 37,
      "updateDate": "2021-05-09 07:52:05",
      "lhb": "2021-05-09 06:32:41",
      "templateCode": "REGULAR",
      "lId": "50-1C-22-6E",
      "sk": "846760",
      "skUpdateDate": "2021-05-08 03:34:22",
      "battery": 29,
      "status": 1
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. Assuming there are no other top-level keys that you care about,

```
jq '.storeId as $storeId | .templateCheck[] | { $storeId, templateCheck: [ . ] }'
```

does just fine to reproduce your example output, or maybe a little more generically (but more confusingly):

```
jq '(. | del(.templateCheck)) as $o | .templateCheck[] | $o + { templateCheck: [.] }'
```

Comment: `storeId: $storeId` here can be abbreviated to `$storeId`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It's working as expected :)